# In WebGL spec, what does ? (question mark) mean?

Tags: webgl, specifications

In the WebGL spec, what does `?` (question mark) mean?

For example: `WebGLBuffer? createBuffer();`

Comment: The value can be null. https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#idl-nullable-type

Answer (score 1):

As @pleup pointed out it means the value can be `null`.  `createBuffer`, `createShader`, `createProgram`, `createTexture`, `createRenderbuffer`, `createFramebuffer` will all return `null` if the context is lost.

This is why you might not want to properties on WebGL objects.

```
 var tex = gl.createTexture();
 tex.width = 320;   // BAD!!
```

If the context is lost that code will fail.